# Const pointer in typedef

Tags: c, matlab, pointers, constants, simulink

What does this line of code do':

```
typedef const real_T    * const * InputRealPtrsType;
```

I think it defines `InputRealPtrsType` as a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant `real_T`.  `real_T` is essentially a `double`, defined to give some cross platform flexibility.  Why would you want to do that?  This definition is in the simulink header file simstruc.h for use in C S-functions.

Comment: Your understanding of the `typedef` is correct. It's difficult to say why someone would do that without knowing the software.

Comment: This is not useful unless it's a function argument, perhaps... ???

Comment: After looking at it a little more, it looks like it's a pointer to an array of pointers.